# Поиск ajax

Tags: ajax, php, json

Здравствуйте делаю поиск, как разобрать json строку:
Сейчас вот так:

**JS**

```
  $(function(){
  $("#adress").keyup(function(){
     var search = $("#adress").val();
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://***/a.php",
       data: {"q": search},
       cache: false,                                 
       success: function(data){
          $("#state").html(data);
       }
     });
     return false;
   });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
if ($_GET['q']){
$movies = array(
  array(
    "title" => "Rear Window",
    "director" => "Alfred Hitchcock",
    "year" => 1954
  ),
  array(
    "title" => "Full Metal Jacket",
    "director" => "Stanley Kubrick",
    "year" => 1987
  ),
  array(
    "title" => "Mean Streets",
    "director" => "Martin Scorsese",
    "year" => 1973
  )
);
echo json_encode($movies);
}else{echo "введите";}
?>
```

**выводит так:**

[{"title":"Rear Window","director":"Alfred Hitchcock","year":1954},{"title":"Full Metal Jacket","director":"Stanley Kubrick","year":1987},{"title":"Mean Streets","director":"Martin Scorsese","year":1973}]

**а я хочу вывести так:**

Rear Window -
Alfred Hitchcock -
1954

Full Metal Jacket - 
Stanley Kubrick - 
1987

И еще один момент, когда я отправляю пустой запрос, хочу получить **"Введите"**

Скажите как разобрать таким образом ответ с сервера?

Comment: @Дмитрий333332 - Вы что нибудь слышали о циклах? К вам с сервера пришел массив, в котором лежат объекты. Пройдитесь по нему циклом в методе `success` и выведите как вам захочется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В параметры вызова ajax добавьте строку dataType='JSON' а далее -

```
success: function(data){
    var result = '';
    for(var i=0,l=data.length;i<l;i++){
        result += data[i].title + ' - ' + data[i].director + ' - ' +data[i].year +'<br>';
    }
    $("#state").html('<p>'+result+'</p>');
}
```

Ну и верстку вместо одевания в параграф - окультурьте по своему вкусу.

Comment: deivan, получилось все, просто застрял на том, что после удаления из input #adress к которому привязано все это дело ни как не хочет меняться содержимое  div #state хотя должно быть "Введите", почему так происходит не знаете?

Comment: т.е. данные которые пришли с сервера и были показаны на странице так и остаются, НО если я оставляю $("#state").html(data); т.е. не разбираю их, тогда после удаления содержимого из input, приходит ответ "Введите" с сервера и отображается вместо предыдущих

Comment: А ну наверное потому что ответ не в формате Jsonа так же хранится переменная с данными?

Comment: на ваш основной вопрос - я ответил. что там вы хотите сделать далее - мне неведомо. Подозреваю, что при удалении поискового слова из строки поиска остается предыдущий результат?.. Тогда надо поставить проверку по содержимому - если поле пустое, то очистить контейнер результата.